# VBA copy/paste value from sheet 1 to sheet 2 on last used row?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy and paste my value from cell B21 on sheet 1 over to column B sheet 2 where there is the next available row?

```
Sub Modify_Trend()


Dim N As Long
   N = Sheets(2).Cells(Sheets(2).Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
   Cells(N, "B").Value = Sheets(1).Range("B21").Value



End Sub
```

Please can someone show me where i am going wrong? This doesn't produce an error or anything and isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fully qualify `Cells(N, "B").Value` to Sheets(2).

Also, you are looking for last row at Column A (and not Column B) :

`N = Sheets(2).Cells(Sheets(2).Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1`

Try the code below:

```
Sub Modify_Trend()

Dim N As Long

With Sheets(2)
    N = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    .Range("B" & N).Value = Sheets(1).Range("B21").Value
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
first get the total number of filled rows of column B in sheet 2.

Then set the value of sheet 2 column B's `last filled row + 1` to value of B21 of sheet 1.

```
Sub Modify_Trend()

    Dim N As Long
       N = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
       Sheet2.Range("B" & N + 1).Value = Sheet1.Range("B21").Value

    End Sub
```

This is the minimal answer as per your original code.